# Remove leading subdirectories in a ZIP file

Tags: zip

Is there any ZIP tools that do similar to the `patch -p1` command, where the first N directory names would get ignored?

My users send me ZIP files that often contain one unnecessary directory, and instead of unzipping them in place, I have to unzip, then go into the subdirectory and move all the files out.  Sometimes it's a zip of thousands of files, and that extra move step can take a while. If 7z or something had `7z x -p1 my_zip.zip`, that first directory could be ignored.  I'd still want to have the directory tree inside that subdirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not finding anything built-in to do the work, I created https://github.com/tgmayfield/zip-dir-strip